# distance calculation between two ports with PostgreSQL and Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL with PostGis and have shapes of all countries loaded.

How can I calculate the shortes sea route between two ports (without intersecting a country shape)

is there a 'standard solution'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use graph theory so long as you have a set of sea-lane type way-points defined.  these would be points along the ship travel lanes with maybe nautical miles between each one indicated.  then use a min path algorithm to find the best travel lane.

of course inreal life this problem has many more variables than just distance i would think.

Comment: hmm, I thought about this but it would require a sheer endless amount of connections

Comment: so how do you envision the calculation?  it can't be the great circle distance, because land masses are in the way.  Where should the ship go if it encounters a land mass?  tightly follow the coast?